# Should the IOC container be responsible for timing observer handler registration?

Tags: architecture, inversion-of-control, observer-pattern

I have a service layer and a view layer set up separately using an IOC container.  I have an observer pattern for my view layer to listen to a change in my service layer. However, on application start up my service layer is starting and notifying observer handlers before my view layer has had a chance to register its response handlers.

Is this a problem with my IOC configuration or my architecture?

*More details*

A domain event happens every so often.  When it does, I want the view layer to react.  I pass the `Observable` domain object to a `ViewInstantiator` using the IOC container at startup, then bind a handler to the `Observable`.  When the handler is triggered, it instantiates a new view and wires it to some other domain objects using a presenter.

Comment: It sounds like you are making requests of your IoC container before its had a chance to bootstrap itself? If this is the case you either need to cope with things not being there yet or make the bootstrap synchronous so that you can be sure by the first request everything is present

Comment: Yes exactly.  Is this an IOC concern or an application concern?  Right now I have the IOC starting the application, but it only waits for components in one tree before firing, so as you say it should wait for all the components to be instantiated, but I cannot find this config option if it exists.  I'm temporarily getting around this issue by adding a run button to the UI.

Comment: It has to be an application concern I think as the container doesn't know when its configuration is complete (as this is done by application code).